# Does stringWithFormat create a retain +1 instance?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring, retain

I'm declaring an ivar of type `NSString` on a class. To initialize the value of this ivar I use the following code:

```
NSString *myVar;

-(void)inAnyMethod
{
   myVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theValue];
}
```

Do I have to release this ivar? According to my understanding, it is not my responsibility. But in most cases, strings that I use in this manner cause leaks.

What am I missing?

Comment: String with format should return an auto-released MSString object. So it should get released in the auto-release pool later. Does the static analyser say that you are leaking?

Comment: What makes you think that there's a leak?

Comment: Instruments. In each 3 of every 4 NSString objects that I use marks a percentage of leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Oscar Gomez answer, note that when you use class methods (those methods with plus sign that you can find in the documentation and are not included in **Oscar Gomez** list, e.g. `stringWithFormat` is one of them), you have not to worry about memory management. If you create your own class method, you should do the same: return an autorelease object.

Regarding your code, it cannot work if you simply assign your ivar to the `NSString` object (returned from that method). In fact, at some point of your application cycle, the object will be released (it has been put in a pool) and your ivar will not reference any object anymore.

The trick: create a `@property` with a `copy` policy or send a `copy` message like the following:

```
myVar = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theValue] copy];
```

Copy is normally used when a class has subclasses of mutable type. Otherwise use `retain`. Once done, you have the possession for that object and you have to remember to release it. If you don't do it you cause a leak.

```
[myVar release];
```

P.S. Since Xcode 4.2 there is a new compiler feature called ARC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Or better yet, just do `myVar = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:"%@", theValue];`

Comment: yes, you are right but since I've seen using the class method, I left as is. :)

Comment: In one sentence that I use alloc is the queen of the leak...100%. I'm finding problems to undestand the release/retain. Seems easy, I reed tons of docs from apple, forums and other sources. And when I apply the rules, the program finds EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in each thing I do :(

Comment: class method or instance method is completely irrelevant. A class method can return a +1 instance, e.g. `+alloc`, `+new`, `+newWithBlah`, and so can an instance method e.g. `copy`, `-newWithBlah`, and vice versa. It's just the name that is relevant

Comment: @user102008 I don't agree with your downvote since you haven't read well my answer. I'm speaking about `stringWithFormatMethod` or similar methods that are not included in **OscarGomez** list. I wrote *In addition to Oscar Gomez...*. My answer was to complete his answer. Cheers.

Comment: @user102008 I also added an edit to explain better this concept.

Comment: but it doesn't matter that it's a class method. it applies equally to instance methods

Comment: @user102008 Ok, but the question it's concerning a class method, not an instance one. As I already said, my answer was only in addition to the first one. Anyway you are free to downvote if you find it not useful. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to `release` it, because that is a convenience method that returns an `autoreleased` object.

The way to know if you are getting something with a retain count of 1 that you will need to release is using the `Cocoa` naming conventions which say that anything that starts with `new`, `alloc` or contains `copy` in the method name will return a `retain` 1 object, the others will return `autoreleased` objects like in this case.